# is this time complexity subexponential?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Is next time complexity sub-exponential?

$O(2^{N^{LOG2(1.5)}}/8)$

unformatted: O((2^N)^LOG2(1.5))/8) just in case I didn't format it properly.

Comment: "next" in what sense?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define subexponential. The definition I generally use is:

$$\textsf{SUBEXP} = \bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0}\textsf{DTIME}(2^{n^\varepsilon})$$

However some authors define:

$$\textsf{SUBEXP} = \textsf{DTIME}(2^{o(n)})$$

Since your function is $2^{n^c}$ for some constant $c<1$, it would be subexponential according to the second but not to the first.

Comment: First definition can be rewritten as $\mathsf{DTIME}(2^{n^{\ o(1)}}\ \ )$, right?